# How to inspect brightness of V channel with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to find a way to evaluate the "brightness" of an image. We're running it through an OCR system that warns us if an image is too bright or dark, but I'm not sure what they're measuring exactly. I've assembled a set of test data divided into 3 categories: No warning, too bright, too dark. I figured I'd do something like convert the image to HSV and inspect the V channel. Frankly, I don't entirely know what I'm doing, and the OpenCV docs for Python are pretty opaque. I got as far as calculating a V channel histogram (although I'm not sure the args are correct):

```
def calc_hist(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv], [2], None, [256], [0,256])
    hist_array = hist.flatten()
```

Again, I'm not sure if inspecting the histogram is the right approach, but basically I'm trying to come up with some value that approximates "brightness" so I can compare these groups of images and try to find a range of values where our OCR software does not throw a warning.

Assuming these are the right histograms, I went on to normalize them and compare the mean standard deviation.

Comment: Can you attach sample images for all the three cases: `No warning, too bright, too dark`

Comment: @ZdaR Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @ AutomaticStatic I have the same problem. did you find a solution for it?